# How can I redirect user twice - Django?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, view

This is my files:

**urls.py**

```
path('add/<str:slug>/', views.addBookmark, name='addBookmark')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def addBookmark(request, slug):
    book = Book.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if BookMark.objects.filter(user=request.user, book=book).exists():
        bookMark = BookMark.objects.get(user=request.user, book=book)
        bookMark.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER")) 

    newBookMark = BookMark.objects.create(user=request.user, book=book)
    newBookMark.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

**Notice**: my view just refresh the page

**Button**

```
<a class="addInBookmarks" href="{% url 'addBookmark' book.slug %}">In bookmarks</a>
```

**What do I have:** When a non-authenticated user tries to add a book in bookmarks I have the next URL pattern:

.../login/?next=/cart/add/harry-potter

It does add an object to the database. However, after the action, it reloads the page and the page is the login page. I need to redirect back to the book page.

**My problem**: For authenticated users, everything works well. However, If a user isn't authenticated, then I wanna have the next scheme: a non-authenticated user clicks on the button -> redirect on the login page -> log in -> add an object in the database(Bookmark model)(using the view above) -> redirect back to the book page.

Comment: But what is the current logic when user are not authenticated ? The actual behavior (because you write only what you want to achieve and not what happen now )

Comment: When the user isn't authenticated, the user clicks on the button, and django redirects him on the login page. My URL is like the URL above. So, when the user enters a login and password, the next URL adds an object in the database and refreshes the page(it's the login page still). So I need to redirect the user back on the book page

Comment: For this you can look into Django redirects which is a mechanism specially for the use case that your describe.